# Template for custom taxonomy for custom post type broken

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to set up my custom template for a custom taxonomy. When I click on a category link to display the custom posts in that specific category, I get the 404 page. My custom post type file name is template-features.php and my taxonomy archive file is archive-features.php. Here is my code to register the taxonomy and post type:

Custom post type and taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'post_type_features', 0 );

function post_type_features() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Features', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Feature', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Features', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Feature:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Features', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Feature', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Feature', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Feature', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Feature', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Features', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'post_features', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'White Glove Labs Features', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'Features' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-star-empty',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_features', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'lv_features_taxonomy', 0 );

function lv_features_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Features', 'Features Taxonomy' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Feature', 'Feature singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Features' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Features' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Feature' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Feature:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Feature' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Feature' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Feature' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Feature Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Features Categories' ),
    );  

    register_taxonomy('features',array('post_features'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'features' ),
    ));

}
```

Just for testing, I have a very basic custom archive file. Here is the code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main-content" class="main-content"> 
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <header class="archive-header">
                <h1 class="archive-title">
                    <?php post_type_archive_title(); ?>
                </h1>
            </header>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code for post type and custom taxonomy, your CPT is `post_features` and taxonomy is `features`.

For single `post_features`, you need to have file named `single-post_features.php`. For archive, create file `taxonomy-features.php`.

See documentation for detail. https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

**Example for single(single-post_features.php):**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    the_title();
    the_content();
  } // end while
} // end if
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Example for Archive(taxonomy-features.php):**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
  the_archive_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
  } // end while
} // end if
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Note:** Please flush your permalink if you are getting 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to [flush the rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after creating your custom post type?
Visit Settings > Permalinks and hit save. ( No need to change anything)